# different plot for same x-axis value in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe, which looks like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': [100, 125, 300, 520], 'b': [250, 270, 278, 248]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[25, 26, 26, 30])
```

```
             a         b
  25        100       250
  26        125       270
  26        300       278
  30        520       248
```

When I try to plot this dataframe with

```
df=sns.lineplot(data=df, dashes=False)
```

the values for 26 are averaged and a error bar shows up. However I want the values for 26 plotted separately.

Comment: Please don't write `df=sns.lineplot(...)` as that will erase the dataframe variable.  `sns.lineplot` returns an `ax`.   You can use `ax = sns.lineplot(x=np.arange(len(df)), y=df['a'])`, then `sns.lineplot(x=np.arange(len(df)), y=df['b'], ax=ax)` and `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df)), ax.index)` to mimic a categorical x-axis.

Comment: Or use `reset_index` to get the ranges: `sns.lineplot(data=df.reset_index(), dashes=False, estimator=None).set(xticks=df.reset_index().index, xticklabels=df.index)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the `estimator` parameter does. See the docs: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, dashes=False, estimator=None)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Is there a way to plot both values next to each other on the x-axis? So the x-axis would look like this: 25, 26, 26, 30